# Using same pipelined function several times in the same query

Tags: oracle, plsql, pipeline

I'm trying to write a pipelined function which uses another pipelined function several times.
So, function `context_Set` receives a cursor and returns results that should be used several times in pipelined funcion `m0` which also receives a cursor as an argument (the sql logic is simplified to `UNION`):

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY PKG_PIPE AS
FUNCTION context_Set(l_res sys_refcursor) 
RETURN resulting_cols_rt PIPELINED 
IS
    recs resulting_record_rt;
BEGIN
    loop
        fetch l_res into recs;
        exit when l_res%notfound;
        PIPE ROW(recs);
    end loop;
    close l_res;
    return;
END context_Set;
-------------------- BEGIN: 01.TEST ---------------------
FUNCTION m0(l_res sys_refcursor) 
RETURN resulting_cols_rt PIPELINED 
IS
    recs resulting_record_rt;
    l_in_res SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    open l_in_res for
        select resulting_record_rt(c1,c2,c3,c4) FROM (
        SELECT * FROM context_Set(l_res)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM context_Set(l_res));
    loop
        fetch l_in_res into recs;
        exit when l_in_res%notfound;
        PIPE ROW(recs);
    end loop;
    close l_in_res;
    return;
END m0;
END PKG_PIPE;
```

and the function is called like the following:

```
open l_res for 'select resulting_record_rt(c1,c2,c3,c4) from (select ... )';
select * 
        FROM PKG_PIPE.m0(l_res);
close l_res;
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
ORA-01001: invalid cursor
```

When `UNION` and the second `SELECT` are removed the function works fine.

Is there some way to rewrite the same to make it work?

Comment: A cursor is a forward-only structure so once you fetch the data from it, you can't go back to the beginning and fetch the data again.  You could fetch the data from the cursor once into a local collection of type `resulting_cols_rt` and restructure the `context_set` function to take in a collection rather than a cursor.  If you are really just trying to cause every row of the result from `context_set` to be duplicated, though, there are easier ways to structure the query so you aren't calling the function twice.

Comment: @Justin Cave I would like to avoid local collections usage since the resulting set can be huge. UNION is used here for simplification only.

Comment: Your pblm is not the table function, but the cursor you're passing to it. Like Justin said, you are fetching data from l_res twice. this raises the error? Try using the with clause to call the function only once with l_res, this should work. (depending on the complexity of your SQL)

Comment: You can't call `context_set` twice passing in the same cursor.  You could open two different cursors which happen to use the same SQL statement and change `m0` to take two cursors.  You could fetch a subset of rows into a local collection and operate on that (depending on what you are really trying to accomplish) and then iterate through those subsets.  You could use a temporary table.  You could potentially change `m0` to only call `context_set` once by doing more of whatever manipulation you are doing in the SQL query.  It's hard to guess which approach might work best.